# How to generate a nullable field of a type that maps to json object with springdoc-openapi / swagger?

Tags: swagger, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui

First of all, the following repository has all the code (and description as well) to reproduce this problem: https://github.com/elgleidson/swagger-problem

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "nonNullableField": "not null",
  "nullableField": null,
  "nonNullableObjectField": {
    "someField": "some value"
  },
  "nullableObjectField": null,
  "nonNullableList": [
    "not null"
  ],
  "nullableList": null,
  "nonNullableObjectList": [
    {
      "someField": "some value"
    }
  ],
  "nullableObjectList": null
}
```

Which is mapped to the following Java classes:

```java
@Value
public class MyResponse {

  @Schema(nullable = false, description = "DO NOT map to json object and DO NOT allow null")
  private final String nonNullableField = "not null";

  @Schema(nullable = true, description = "DO NOT map to json object and allows null")
  private final String nullableField = null;

  @Schema(nullable = false, description = "map to json object and DOES NOT allow null")
  private final MyClass nonNullableObjectField = new MyClass(nonNullableField);

  @Schema(nullable = true, description = "map to json object and allows null")
  private final MyClass nullableObjectField = null;

  @ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(nullable = false, description = "list that DOES NOT map to json object and DOES NOT allow null"))
  private final List<String> nonNullableList = List.of(nonNullableField);

  @ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(nullable = true, description = "list that DOES NOT map to json object and allow null"))
  private final List<String> nullableList = null;

  @ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(nullable = false, description = "list that map to json object and DOES NOT allow null"))
  private final List<MyClass> nonNullableObjectList = List.of(nonNullableObjectField);

  @ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(nullable = true, description = "list that map to json object and allow null"))
  private final List<MyClass> nullableObjectList = null;

}

@Value
@Schema(description = "my class description")
public class MyClass {

  @Schema(description = "my class field description")
  private final String someField;

}
```

When I go to `/v3/api-docs` (or `/swagger-ui.html`) the following documentation is generated:

```
{
  "MainResponse": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "nonNullableField": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "DO NOT map to json object and DO NOT allow null"
      },
      "nullableField": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "DO NOT map to json object and allows null",
        "nullable": true
      },
      "nonNullableObjectField": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass"
      },
      "nullableObjectField": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass"
      },
      "nonNullableList": {
        "type": "array",
        "description": "list that DOES NOT map to json object and DOES NOT allow null",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        } 
      },
      "nullableList": {
        "type": "array",
        "description": "list that DOES NOT map to json object and allow null",
        "nullable": true,
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "nonNullableObjectList": {
        "type": "array",
        "description": "list that map to json object and DOES NOT allow null",
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass"
        }
      },
      "nullableObjectList": {
        "type": "array",
        "description": "list that map to json object and allow null",
        "nullable": true,
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "MyClass": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "someField": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "my class field description"
      }
    },
    "description": "my class description",
    "nullable": true
  }
}
```

As you can see, for the fields whose types are not mapped to `object` the documentation is generated as expected. The same doesn't happen for `nullableObjectField`: the `nullable` property is put in `MyClass` definition instead of the field.

I would like to generate the following documentation instead:

```
{
  "MainResponse": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "nonNullableField": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "DO NOT map to json object and DO NOT allow null"
      },
      "nullableField": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "DO NOT map to json object and allows null",
        "nullable": true
      },
      "nonNullableObjectField": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass",
        "description": "map to json object and DOES NOT allow null"
      },
      "nullableObjectField": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass",
        "description": "map to json object and allows null",
        "nullable": true
      },
      "nonNullableList": {
        "type": "array",
        "description": "list that DOES NOT map to json object and DOES NOT allow null",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        } 
      },
      "nullableList": {
        "type": "array",
        "description": "list that DOES NOT map to json object and allow null",
        "nullable": true,
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "nonNullableObjectList": {
        "type": "array",
        "description": "list that map to json object and DOES NOT allow null",
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass"
        }
      },
      "nullableObjectList": {
        "type": "array",
        "description": "list that map to json object and allow null",
        "nullable": true,
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass"
        }
      }      
    }
  },
  "MyClass": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "someField": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "my class field description"
      }
    },
    "description": "my class description"
  }
}
```

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: It seems like a swagger-core bug, so I have opened a issue on their project: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3518

Comment: i think, this question should be flagged as answered then ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its a swagger bug:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3518